# What's a good PHP Active Record library?

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

I've been using CodeIgniter for some quite time, and I've been extremely happy with its Active Record stuff. It's great to query the database with it.

Recently I've started a new project and I can't use such a framework anymore.

Is there a simple PHP Active Record library that does its job and gets out of the way (similar to CodeIgniter's version)?

Comment: I don't know (or care) if this is the right place to say this. But I have to say that this is a very constructive question and is absolutely on topic.I am really disappointed that it has been closed.

Comment: It seems like phpactiverecord is the only good active record implementation in PHP out there. Unfortunately it is slowly dying by judging from the commits on their github account. For some reason people are moving towards Doctrine and Propel which both are horrible Hibernate clones. As if PHP didn't suck enough already. *Shaking my head in disbelief*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you explicitly looking for an implementation of the [Active Record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)?

If not you might want to look into an object-relational mapper (ORM), such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/). See also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library).

Comment: yes i am really looking for the Active Record pattern. ORM usually deals with code-generation which i'm not fond of.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check out http://cinchapps.com/active_record/

Answer (score -1):

You may want to have a look at [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this easy to use active [record class](http://www.eeqqoo.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61%3aphp-table-row-class&catid=35%3aphp&Itemid=54) which also uses an [MySQL abstract layer](http://www.eeqqoo.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57%3amysqlhandler-v0123&catid=35%3aphp&Itemid=54).