# PHP: is there 3rd party library --> active record like in CodeIgniter (same syntax)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, pdo

I was wondering if  there was a 3rd partly library for an active record like CodeIgniter has?
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

I have many sites that can't use CodeIgniter now because they are not build on a framework.
I really like the CodeIgniter active record class though.
Therefore i was wondering if there was a 3rd party class that has the same syntax as the CodeIgniter one.
I found some PDO like the PHP standard one but I don't like the workflow.

Does anyone know a similar library, or know how to extract the active record library out of the CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: The codeigniter library probably is not OSI certified, so I would step away using it in your own projects. But there should be a lot of other, better licensed database libraries that follow a similar convention. You could easily write a wrapper I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

There are two famous ones:

- [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/)
- [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

For comparison between these two, check out:

- [PHP ORMs: Doctrine vs. Propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062473/php-orms-doctrine-vs-propel)

Answer (score 0):

propel and doctrine are ORMs, if you just want to use active record you should look at this SO thread: [What's a good PHP Active Record library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438467/whats-a-good-php-active-record-library)

On a side note, CI is open source, just not OSI certified. That alone should not be a reason NOT to use it. 
http://www.hopstudios.com/blog/is_codeigniter_actually_open_source for an in-depth view.